# WCF access to Windows Service Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I have an web app (asp.net) which calls a WCF (C#). The WCF calls Windows Service to perform a task. Unfortunately when WCF calls the windows service I get error as

`Cannot open appservice service on computer '.'`

The WebApp, WCF and appservice all are same machine (Windows 2012). WebApp, WCF and appservice are running under account `acctname` which is added to administrator group.

The appservice is running, its just that WCF cannot call the appservice.
Any idea how to resolve the issue ?.

Here is the sample code in WCF, which calls the windows service (appservice)

```
try 
{
    string serviceName = "appservice ";
    ServiceController niuService = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    niuService.MachineName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVICE_MACHINE_NAME"];

    if (niuService == null)
    {
        returnObject.IsSuccessful = false;
        returnObject.MessageCollection.Add(new Message{Description = "Service <" + serviceName +
                        "> ON Machine <" + niuService.MachineName + "wasn't found when starting fl"});
    }
    else if (niuService.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        returnObject.IsSuccessful = false;
        returnObject.MessageCollection.Add(new Message{Description = "Service <" + serviceName +
                        "> wasn't running when starting fl"});
    }
    else
    {
        niuService.ExecuteCommand((int)ServiceCustomCommands.START_FL);
        returnStatus = true;
        returnObject.IsSuccessful = true;
        returnObject.BusinessObject = true;
    }
}
```

//relevant windows service code

```
  protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
        {
            base.OnCustomCommand(command);
            EventLogEntryType status = EventLogEntryType.Information;
            bool cmdUnknown = false;
            bool resp = false;

            switch (command)
            {
                case (int)ServiceCustomCommands.CHECK_DB_CONN:
                    resp = ApiFlashing.Instance.CheckDBconnection();
                    break;
                case (int)ServiceCustomCommands.START_FL:
                    resp = flON = ApiFlashing.Instance.StartFlashing(0);  
                    break;


//remaining code comes here
```

Comment: Windows Services are generally not intended to be interactive applications.  Can you provide more information and maybe some code examples illustrating what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please provide more info: How exactly do you call the Windows service? What exact error(s) do you get?

Comment: I updated my post with sample code per request

Comment: Can you post the relevant Windows Service code?  Did you override the `OnCustomCommand` in the service?

Comment: I also added the relevant windows service code ?